# Can't get log4j to work in a maven web project on a JBoss Server

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

I created a log4j.properties and I inserted it into ../WEB-INF/classes/
Here is the properties file

```
# Define the root logger with appender FA
log4j.rootLogger=Debug,FA

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FA.File=c:\log.log
log4j.appender.MaxFileSize=50MB

# Set the immediate flush to true
log4j.appender.FA.ImmediateFlush=true

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM/dd HH\:mm\:ss} %-5p %30.30c %x - %m\n
```

I have a simple LOG statement in a class that runs at startup. I am seeing that in the console -- so that LOG statement is working fine.

JBoss 5.1 internal Log4j seems to be taking precedence and nothing I've found online is fixing it.

Any suggestions I could try and report back or any additional information I need to provide?

Thanks everyone!

EDIT:

I changed it from a properties file to an xml. Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <param name="file" value="program.log" />
        <param name="append" value="true"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.program">
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        <appender-ref reg="fileAppender" />
    </logger>


</log4j:configuration>
```

I renamed my company name and the program to just "com.program", so those are just placeholders.

EDIT:

Here is the directory structure:

```
src
 ---main
    ---java
    ---resources
    ---webapp
       ---META-INF
       ---WEB-INF
          ---classes
             +log4j.xml
          +jboss-deployment-structure.xml
```

Maven pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to put `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in `WEB-INF`.

Configuration `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>       
  </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Do I put it under WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: Normally, there `classes` folder and `lib` are under `WEB-INF` directory. make sure to put all of your jar file under `WEB-INF/lib/`

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and it still is not creating the log. I did change to a .xml file for my log4j configuration which I posted in main post.

Comment: I added a bounty if you can potentially help me further :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this problem.

The default jboss log4j properties file gets precedence over your application log4j properties file because the classloader loads the resources in following order

```
bootstrap > system > common > webapp
```

You can

1. Either replace existing conf/log4j.xml with your copy to quickly get your logging needs in action. This is a quick and dirty solution.
2. Or, you can treat this problem by fine tuning the logging which is discussed in http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Maven wasn't added log4j.jar to the lib folder. I should of caught it sooner but it is all set!!!